# Pentaho Web Services Lookup can't load the url

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pdi

I put de url and try load, but happen this error.

[image]

I'm sure that it's work, because I can call this url in SOAPUI...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you report are two different things:

1. In your first screenshot, there is an error message that your program cannot load the WSDL document, because one of the referenced XML Schema is not accessible.
2. In SoapUI you demonstrate that the target service is alive.

Please note that SoapUI is very tolerant when parsing the WSDL. Your WSDL might have errors, but when you import the WSDL into SoapUI, SoapUI skips and ignores the errors. You can consume the target service then.

You need to check your WSDL and all referenced XML Schemas and to make sure they are accessible (it can be a network issue or other cause).

Comment: Thanks Karel, I checked the schema location is TicketEndpointService_schema1.xsd, but when I create the simulation service, I can access the wsdl in my browser, but the schemalocation is this schemaLocation = "mockTicketEndpointPortBinding?" WSDL & interface = TicketEndpointPortBinding & part = TicketEndpointService_schema1.xsd ", but when I try the search in the step, the PDI gives me another message, stating that there is no Service_schema1.xsd in the same directory